# Why are the constants returned from function fft from stats package in R not returning an aproximation of the signal when evaluated?

Tags: python, r, math, fft, statsmodels

I've been trying to get the frequency and amplitude of all the values of a signal applying the stats.:fft() function.
My real signal is as shown in the next picture:[image]

The signal is measured every hour.

This is the code used to create the signal index, I'm not sure why I have to always make the integration from 0 to 1, but I read that works so that's why I use it here.

```
samp_freq <- 168

time_interval <- 1/samp_freq

signal_index <- seq(0, 1, by=time_interval)

plot(x = signal_index,y = dt$train.sensores_sum_entrada[1:169], type = "l")
```

After applying the function transform and evaluating the constant of each frequency component, when plotting the results I get something similar to this:
[image]

The code for generating this result is as follows:

```
f_component <- stats::fft(z = dt$train.sensores_sum_entrada[1:169])

f_coef <- abs(f_component)

plot(f_coef)
main_coef <- (abs(stats::fft(dt$train.sensores_sum_entrada))/(6966/2))[1:500]
normal_f_compon <- f_coef/ (168/2)
main_coef <- normal_f_compon[1:(168/2)]
coef_table <- data.table(frequency = 1:length(main_coef),amplitude = main_coef)
model_evaluated <- lapply(X = 1:length(coef_table$frequency),FUN = function(i) coef_table$amplitude[i]*sin(2*pi*coef_table$frequency[i]*signal_index))
plot(Reduce(f = `+`,model_evaluated),type = "l")
```

I would appreciate it if someone knows how can I fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to reconstruct a signal from its fft. You could use `fft(f_component, inverse = TRUE)` for this, though if you want to do it manually, you could try this approach.

First I will produce some dummy data:

```r
f <- function(x)
{
  (sin(x * pi * 12) + 1) * 2000 +
  cos(x * pi * 54) * 200 -
  sin(x * pi * 3.6) * 250
}

x <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 168)

plot(x, f(x), type = "l")
```

[image]

And I get the Fourier transform:

```
f_components <- fft(f(x))
```

And I can reverse it like this:

```r
freqs   <- seq_along(f_components) - 1
fourier <- pi * -2 * complex(imaginary = 1) * freqs/length(f_components)
y <- sapply(freqs, function(i) sum(f_components * exp(fourier * i)))
y <- c(y[1], rev(y[-1])) / length(f_components)

lines(x, y, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>